# Как задать последовательное подключение функций?

Tags: javascript

Ребятки, а подскажите, как задать последовательное подключение функций? Есть два работающих скрипта, и один должен подключаться раньше другого, иначе не будет работать совсем. Ситуация омрачается тем, что на запрос "последовательный вывод javascript" или "последовательное подключение javascript" поисковик выдает не то, предлагает почитать, как по очереди вывести на экран картинки или посчитать кроликов. В общем, может быть, подскажете, какую литературку, статейку или хотя бы как запрос сформировать так, чтобы хоть что-то по теме найти, а то со вчера уже тонну букв прочла, и все оказались бесполезны.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file оно, нет?

Comment: [require.js](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/10/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-requirejs/)?

Comment: @Etki, исходя из вопросов, рановато ещё require.js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript всегда выполняется последовательно ровно до тех пор, пока вы не используете асинхронные методы. То есть, если первая функция вызвана выше в коде, чем вторая, то она и будет вызвана первой и только потом все остальное.

Но все меняется, когда вы используете асинхронную модель, а именно таймеры, анимации, Ajax и прочее. Тут уже стоит отслеживать состояние приложения и принимать решения по вызову функций. Есть колбеки, есть вызов функций после синхронных операций, есть проверка значений по таймеру.

В любом случае, если функции выполняются не по порядку вызова, значит вы имеете дело с "асинхронным javascript программированием". Однозначного лекарства на данный вопрос нету, а подробная информация или код проблемного участка не приведен.

Comment: нечего там приводить. напартачено и криво сделано до меня.подскажите автора книги какой, или блога так, чтобы можно было разобраться с работой JS? у меня пока только том от 2008 года, но там информация уже не актуальна. за автора была бы премного благодарна. ну и за асинхронность. но она без книженции и детального разбора не пойдет.

Comment: @Anna Frank, вот вам учебник по JS: http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Благодарствую.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Предлагаете каждую функцию в отдельный файл вынести?

Comment: если они все независимые, то да. 
Но почти всегда функции можно объединить в рабочие группы.